# Cat clone in C++

Tags: c++

I wrote this `cat` clone in C++. It does two things

1. prints the content of file if only one file is given.
2. concatenate and print contents of file if more than one file are provided.

I am especially concerned with the overloading of `<<` for the class `CLI`. I mainly
wanted to gain some abstraction with this.

Below is the code for the program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

// Represents the input provided by the user ..
class Input{
 std::vector<std::string> fileCollection;
public:
 std::vector<std::string> invalidFile;
 Input(std::vector<std::string> fileList){
   fileCollection = fileList;
 }
 std::string get_file_contents(){
  // return contents of each file..
  std::stringstream file_buffer;
  for (auto file : fileCollection){
   std::ifstream newFile(file);
   if (newFile.good()){
    file_buffer << newFile.rdbuf();
    newFile.close();
   } else {
    invalidFile.emplace_back(file);
   }
  }
  return file_buffer.str();
 }
};


// represents the whole app we are working on ..
class CLI{
 Input* newInput;
public:
CLI(std::vector<std::string> fileNames){
 newInput = new Input(fileNames);
}

 friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, CLI* myCli){
  os << myCli -> newInput -> get_file_contents();
  if ((myCli -> newInput -> invalidFile).size() > 0){
   std::string msg;
   for (auto file : myCli -> newInput -> invalidFile){
    msg = "Error: " + file + ": No such file or directory\n";        
    os << msg;       
    }
   }
   return os;
  }
 };


int main(int argc, char** argv){
  std::vector<std::string> fileNames;
  for (int i = 1; i < argc ; ++i){
   fileNames.emplace_back(argv[i]);
  }
  auto myCLI = new CLI(fileNames);
  // calls the overloaded << operator
  // displays the content of files
  std::cout << myCLI;
 }
```

Answer (score 15):

We never `delete myCLI`.  It's not clear why we allocate this object in dynamic storage with `new`, rather than simply instantiating as a local.

We always return an exit status of 0 (success), regardless of whether the inputs were successfully read or the output successfully written.

It looks like we write error messages to the standard output stream.  They should go to the *error* stream, `std::cerr`.

We don't need any classes for this simple utility.  It seems massively overcomplicated to me.  And inefficient, because we read each file entirely into memory before starting to write it.

A much simpler version doesn't need any user-defined classes at all:

```
#include <cerrno>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    try {
        std::cout.exceptions(std::ios::badbit|std::ios::failbit);

        std::ifstream is;
        is.exceptions(std::ios::badbit|std::ios::failbit);

        for (auto filename: std::ranges::subrange(argv+1, argv+argc)) {
            is.open(filename, is.binary);
            std::copy(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{is},
                      std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{},
                      std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>{std::cout});
            is.clear();
            is.close();
        }
    } catch (std::exception const& e) {
        if (errno) {
            std::cerr << strerror(errno) << '\n';
        } else {
            std::cerr << e.what() << '\n';
        }
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
}
```

Comment: I removed the heap allocation and set those allocations to stack, returned `0` from the main.
I am using a `class` because I have plans to extend this further for more features.
I am concerned with the inefficiency now, any suggestions for avoiding copying by keeping the structure of the code same. Do I need to print as soon as I get the character, but how can I achieve this if I have a overloaded `<<`?

Comment: @AbhilekhGautam: Classes do NOT help adding features, magically. Especially when writing small utilities like `cat`, which are used in pipes, try to _think_ in terms of pipes: what is the data-flow within the application? What steps are you executing? You need functions (steps), but not necessarily an orchestrator class.

Comment: Minor improvement, it's better to be clearer with the auto for entries you don't plan on modifying: `for (const auto& filename :  std::ranges::subrange(argv+1, argv+argc)) {`

Comment: @mascoj, yes, `const` might be valuable there - but probably not `&` for a simple pointer.  I think `const char *const filename` is probably better choice, as that shows we don't modify the string contents either.

Comment: @TobySpeight Yes you are right, when I saw subrange I assumed a wrapper would be used when iterating but that doesn't seem the case.

Answer (score 11):

Style Comment:

The indent of one space is a bit small. More standard is 4 but please a minium of 2 spaces. Some of your functions are very crowded vertically. Some blank lines in logical places to help readability would definitely be appreciated.

---

Here is a simplification of loading the `fileNames` vector:

```
  std::vector<std::string> fileNames;
  for (int i = 1; i < argc ; ++i){
   fileNames.emplace_back(argv[i]);
  }
```

Could be written as:

```
  std::vector<std::string>  fileNames(argv + 1, argv + argc);
```

---

Don't dynamically allocate memory when an automatic variable will.

```
   auto myCLI = new CLI(fileNames);
```

Why not just:

```
   CLI   myCLI(fileNames);
```

It's shorter!

---

Memory management.

You do realize that this leaks:

```
 auto myCLI = new CLI(fileNames);

 // and this:
 newInput = new Input(fileNames);
```

Note: The problem is not only the loss of the memory, but the loss of not calling the destructor. You create objects, so they correctly clean up after themselves, but if the destructor is not called, they can't clean up their own mess.

The other problem is you don't have a destructor to clean up `newInput`. Every call to `new` should (**MUST**) be matched with a call to delete. Which is why we prefer you to use automatic variables rather than dynamic in the first place.

This is just sloppy. (Automatic fail in any C++ class).

Note: Modern C++ rarely uses `new` and `delete` at all. You should be using `automatic` objects by preference, if you do need to dynamically create objects then they should be managed via either smart pointers or containers. You only need to use `new/delete` if you are creating a new container or smart pointer or diving very deep into the abstraction.

---

Design: Why do you load the file content into memory, then print it out? This means your application is limited to files that are a fraction of the memory on your machine.

Sure; you could use an intermediate buffer to read large chunks from the file. **BUT** The `std::fstream` types already do this internally (so you are simply replicating their work if you did it again). Now I could see replicating this buffering if you are doing it as a class exercise but not in real life.

The [simplest way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10195497/14065) to copy a stream to a stream is simply stream the buffer:

```
std::ifstream  src(fromFileName, std::ios::binary);

std::cout << src.rdbuf();
```

I would prefer this over using `std::copy()` as suggested by @Toby.

---

A Copy of @Toby's code with two minor changes I would do:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>

#include <cstring>
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    try {
        std::ifstream is;
        // I really like this.
        // Normally we don't do this but in this situation it is
        // a very clever way of handling the error cases.
        is.exceptions(is.badbit|is.failbit);
        std::cout.exceptions(is.badbit|is.failbit);

        // Clever use of ranges :-)
        for (auto filename: std::ranges::subrange(argv+1, argv+argc)) {
            is.open(filename, std::ios::binary);

            std::cout << is.rdbuf();
            
            is.close();
        }
    } catch (std::exception const& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << '\n';

        // Rather than return an error
        // I would re-throw the exception.
        throw;

        // This can provide more information to the host OS.
    }
}
```

Comment: For some reason, streaming the buffer didn't work when I tried it.  And I'm too busy today to root out the cause, so `std::copy()` it is.

Comment: Are you sure that rethrowing is right from `main()`?  On my systems, the default exception handler will abort, causing a core dump.  Which seems like overkill for the common case of file not found, or not readable.

Comment: And thanks for spotting the other `new` that I missed in that dense mass!

Comment: @TobySpeight My compiler does not have subrange yet. So I had to use a `std::vector<std::string> filename(argv + 1 , argv + argc);` then loop over that. Other wise the code seemed to work.

Comment: @TobySpeight ReThrowing in main. I do that because when my app crashes, I want the core dump. But I suppose for simple example applications like this `return EXIT_FAILURE;` is probably better.

Comment: Agreed, when the error is caused by the programmer.  Less so when it's due to the user or an anticipated environment problem such as trying to write to a full filesystem, because people don't generally want core dumps scattered all over their filesystems.  If we can understand the cause then the code could choose whether or not to throw - but that's a whole new review then, I think!

Comment: You have `<ranges>` but not `subrange`?  That's surprising.  You could probably use a vector of `std::string_view` (or even of `char const*`, like the view) safely if you didn't want the overhead of full-on string objects.

Comment: Why catch at all? Most runtimes will cause `what()` to be printed anyway when an unhandled exception is thrown.

Comment: @G.Sliepen I catch to force all destructors to be called. If an exception escapes main it is implementation defined if the destructors are called. By catching you force the destructors to be correctly called before you re-throw.

Comment: @TobySpeight On MacOS, using clang++ from both the latest Xcode (14.0) and also seemingly a `brew install`-ed clang 15.0.6, I also do not have `subrange`: `cat.cpp:17:36: error: no member named 'subrange' in namespace 'std::ranges'`. I'm compiling with `-std=c++20` and both with and without some homebrew clang compiler flags.